# Update Terraform map function to "tomap"

Tags: terraform

I inherited some older TF code and I noticed that some of the code is using deprecated functions like map(object){}. I would like to update this code since map is no longer used as per this [document](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/map.html).

Here is an excerpt from the old code:

```
variable "application_gateways" {
  type = map(object({
    name                       = string
    webapp_firewall_policy_key = string
    zones                      = list(string)
    enable_http2               = bool
    sku = object({
      name     = string
      tier     = string
      capacity = number
    })
```

Can I update it using [tomap](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/tomap.html) like this or is it more complicated?

```
variable "application_gateways" {
  type = tomap({
    name                       = string
    webapp_firewall_policy_key = string
    zones                      = list(string)
    enable_http2               = bool
    sku = object({
      name     = string
      tier     = string
      capacity = number
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is all you need to do.

No further config is needed.

Comment: thanks. I also saw another syntax that was weird. It specifies type = map(string). I was not aware that map could be used for strings.

Comment: Yes it can be :) https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/type-constraints.html#map-

Comment: I see. so just change it to tomap(string) I am assuming?

Comment: No no - that's an actual collection type, not a function like `tomap`. A `map(string)` can be the output of `tomap` - does that make sense?

Comment: I think I would need to see an example. In this case, it is a variable declaration in this code. It looks like they are creating a map of strings for key:value pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to use just 'object' keyword outside as well:
**variable "application_gateways" {
type = object({**

```
variable "application_gateways" {
    type = object({
    name                       = string
    webapp_firewall_policy_key = string
    zones                      = list(string)
    enable_http2               = bool
    sku = object({
      name     = string
      tier     = string
      capacity = number
        })
    })
```